# Use Meteor Iron Router data context in regular JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, iron-router

Iron Router Code:

```
this.route('petProfile', {
    path: '/pets/:_id',
    data: function(){
        return Adoptees.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
```

This is pretty straightforward. If I have a `petName` key for each object in the `Adoptees` collection, I can just use handlebars templates to access the data context.

petProfile.html:

```
<template name="petProfile">
    <h1>{{petName}}</h1>
</template>
```

But say that I want to have the data context in the associated javascript file:

petProfile.js:

```
Template.petProfile.rendered = function() {
    var petName = //How do I get the pet name from the data context in Iron Router?
}
```

Great, it works. So based off of saimeunt's answer, I can just do:

petProfile.js:

```
Template.petProfile.rendered = function() {
    var petName = this.data.petName;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `created / rendered / destroyed` callback, you can access the data context using `this.data.field`, because `this` is mapped to the template instance.

In helpers and event handlers, you can access it using `this.field` because `this` is mapped directly to the data context.

Comment: could you tell me how you know to do this? I read the iron router documentation and there doesn't seem to be any mention of this.

Comment: It has nothing to do with iron-router, this is plain Meteor API : http://docs.meteor.com/#template_data

Answer (score -3):

data can be accessed in the Template using 'this'

so

```
this.petName
```

Comment: You mean in the JS file, inside Template.petProfile.rendered, I can just do this.petName?